# Array manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey I am stuck in the middle of my code. I am getting some input data from my partner and I get an array. At the 0 index of the array there are 3 strings. The array looks like this

```
array
0 => 
   object(MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PatentIdJson)[1405]
   private 'patentId' => string 'EP.02708872.A' (length=13)
   private 'jsonData' => string '{"ops:world-patent-data": {
    "@xmlns":   {
    "ops": "http://ops.epo.org",
    "$": "http://www.epo.org/exchange",
    "ccd": "http://www.epo.org/ccd",
    "xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  },
  "ops:meta":   {
  "@name": "elapsed-time",
  "@value": "69"
  }
  private 'status' => string 'Found' (length=5)
```

What I am interested in is the 'jsonData' String. Can I covert this whole array to a multidimensional array or just get the 'jsonData' and convert it into an array so that I get the information what I need from the 'jsonData'.

Thanks

Comment: Does the `MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PatentIdJson` class have a method to return `jsonData`?

Comment: yes getjsonData() in the Entity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is json_decode and you can do the following:

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($myArray[0]->getjsonData(), true);
```

That will generate an object from the jsonData your partner is providing in the array

Comment: but to get the assocciated array we need to pass true as 2nd parameter to json_decode

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you can get to the data using:

```
$jsonData = $your_array[0]->getjsonData();
```

Assuming that the `MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PatentIdJson` extends the `MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity` class.